# Strange/unexplainable behaviour of Eclipse and multicast packets

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, multicast

I have a very similar behaviour as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264948/link-scope-ipv6-multicast-packets-suddenly-not-routable-on-a-macbook-pro):

- running on a Mac Book Pro, Snow Leopard
- using Multicast Sockets to send and receive packets on localhost

I'm using Eclipse and observed the following behaviour when the client / server are started from within the workspace:

- if the wireless interface (airport) is up and running, the client does *not* receive any packets
- if the interface is turned off, everything works as expected

But what I don't understand is:

- if I create a JAR and run the code in any console -> all good! Just Eclipse seems not to like airport ;-)
- depending on what wireless network I'm connected to, the above behaviour might change, i.e. it also works if airport is enabled (for example @ Uni)

Does anyone have an idea 'bout this?

Cheers

Below the straightforward code for server / client:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    String multicastAddress = "224.0.0.2";
    int multicastPort = 8000;
    MulticastSocket socket = null;
    try {
        try {
            InetAddress multicastGoup = InetAddress.getByName(multicastAddress);
            socket = new MulticastSocket(multicastPort);
            socket.joinGroup(multicastGoup);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while (true) {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            System.out.println("BEFORE RECEIVE: listening on " + multicastAddress + ":" + multicastPort);
            socket.receive(packet);
            System.out.println("PACKET RECEIVED");

            System.err.println("Client received: " + new String(packet.getData()));
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        socket.close();
    }

}
```

Server:

```
    public void run() {
    MulticastSocket socket = null;
    try {
        String multicastAddress = "224.0.0.2";
        int multicastPort = 8000;
        InetAddress multicastGoup = InetAddress.getByName(multicastAddress );
        socket = new MulticastSocket(multicastPort);
        socket.joinGroup(multicastGoup);

        byte[] data = new String("Teststring").getBytes();

        while (true) {
            socket.send(new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, multicastGoup, multicastPort));
            System.out.println("SERVER: Datagram sent");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this problem is related to what interface the `joinGroup()` method chooses as default - and this (the default) varies according to Eclipse settings and available intefaces). Can you select an inteface to use when calling `joinGroup()` and see if the problem continues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Class MulticastSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html):

```
void  joinGroup(SocketAddress mcastaddr, NetworkInterface netIf)
          Joins the specified multicast group at the specified interface.
```

Try using a specific interface so your joinGroup doesn't fall into the default - which may vary according on available, open ones or due to Eclipse settings.

```
joinGroup

public void joinGroup(SocketAddress mcastaddr,
                      NetworkInterface netIf)
               throws IOException

  Joins the specified multicast group at the specified interface.

  If there is a security manager, this method first calls its
  checkMulticast method with the mcastaddr argument as its argument.

  Parameters:
    mcastaddr - is the multicast address to join
    netIf - specifies the local interface to receive
        multicast datagram packets,
      -- here is the catch
      or null to defer to the interface set by
        setInterface(InetAddress) or 
        setNetworkInterface(NetworkInterface)
```