# macOS en5 network can't be turned off

Tags: macos, networking, macos-high-sierra, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have MacBook Pro 2017, and currently am using High Sierra. I have specific requirement by some software to disable all networks. But this en5 network can't be disabled.

I have removed everything from Networks in network preferences. When I try to disable it through terminal `sudo ifconfig en5 down` I get **ifconfig: down: permission denied**.

Few days ago I ran across some article saying I need to change some permits to my sudo user but I can't find that article now :(. 
Here are some more info on en5 from terminal

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist | grep en5
        "BSD Name" = en5;
        IOPathMatch = "IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14/XHC1@14000000/HS03@14100000/iBridge@14100000/NCM Data@5/AppleUSBNCMData/en5";


en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether ac:de:48:00:11:22 
inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7 
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
media: autoselect
status: active
```

Any Idea how to disable this en5 network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot disable en5 in your mac probably because you have the touchbar version. en5 is reserved for iBridge interface (used by the touchbar) therefore it's protected and you won't be able to disable it.